# while() loop array merge() accessing those values outside of the while() in array form $row['field_name']

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

This while parses my query. The $merge var contains the exact structure I need.

What I am trying to do is take the $merge data and process it as an array and get each value in a $row[0], $row[1], $row[3] etc... outside of the while loop.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($query)) {
    $industries = explode(",", $row[13]);
    unset($row[13]);
    $merge = array_merge($row, $industries);
}
```

Example of $merge output:

```
Array
(
   [0] => 3122
   [1] => Painting Services
   [2] => 
   [3] => 1234567 Tew Street
   [4] => 
   [5] => Andover
   [6] => MA
   [7] => 
   [8] => 01801
   [9] => 000-555-1212
   [10] => 000-555-1212
   [11] => 
   [12] => www.not-a-real-site.ooo
   [13] => Roofing 
)

Array
(
   [0] => 3123
   [1] => Hobow Corporation
   [2] => 
   [3] => 115 Sound Plaza, 117th Floor
   [4] => 
   [5] => Woodbridge
   [6] => NJ
   [7] => 
   [8] => 07111
   [9] => 000-555-1212
   [10] => 000-555-1212
   [11] => 
   [12] => www.not-a-real-site.ooo
   [13] => Energy
)
```

Comment: I think I might have just solved this problem. Will post my answer if it all works out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$rows = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($query)) {
    $industries = explode(",", $row[13]);
    unset($row[13]);
    $rows[] = array_merge($row, $industries);
}
```

Comment: I used a counter and foreach() to access each value from your example: foreach ($rows[$i] as $value) { ...

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.